# OpenTBS chart 'Two charts in one' data structure advice needed

Tags: opentbs

I'm putting together a docx template which contains a number of graphs which can have their data changed using OpenTBS. I've successfully managed to do a few. One is giving me problems. It is a kind of 'two graphs in one' scenario. See screenshot. I've given the chart the title 'Susceptibility & Reporting by Time Over Time'. Can you even have two charts in one in this way? I've made a number of different attempts using the different array structures listed in the OpenTBS docs without any success. I am getting the error 'TinyButStrong Error OpenTBS Plugin: (ChartChangeSeries) 'Susceptibility & Reporting by Time Over Time' : unable change series 'Jan 2016 Campaign #1' in the chart 'chart15' : Name of the series not found. The process is ending, unless you set NoErr property to true'. See code. Thanks.[image]

```
$chartName = 'Susceptibility &amp; Reporting by Time Over Time';
    $newLegend = false;
    $newValues = array(
        array(
            'Reported Email Correctly',
            'First Link Clicked / Attachment Run'
        ),
        array(180, 180)
    );
    $SeriesNameOrNum = 'Jan 2016 Campaign #1';
    $TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_CHART, $chartName, $SeriesNameOrNum, $newValues, $newLegend);

    $newValues = array(
        array(
            'Reported Email Correctly',
            'First Link Clicked / Attachment Run'
        ),
        array(140, 140)
    );
    $SeriesNameOrNum = 'April 2016 Campaign #2';
    $TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_CHART, $chartName, $SeriesNameOrNum, $newValues, $newLegend);

    $newValues = array(
        array(
            'Reported Email Correctly',
            'First Link Clicked / Attachment Run'
        ),
        array(100, 100)
    );
    $SeriesNameOrNum = 'Oct 2016 Campaign #3';
    $TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_CHART, $chartName, $SeriesNameOrNum, $newValues, $newLegend);

    $newValues = array(
        array(
            'Reported Email Correctly',
            'First Link Clicked / Attachment Run'
        ),
        array(80, 80)
    );
    $SeriesNameOrNum = 'Oct 2016 Campaign #4';
    $TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_CHART, $chartName, $SeriesNameOrNum, $newValues, $newLegend);
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EmWk.png

Comment: Difficult to say without knowing more about the actual series defined with this chart (in edit mode). Some charts have they series and categories pivoted. If first suggest that you rename the series without the `#` which may be a special character that cheats OpenTBS.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. In actual fact I was doing it right but you have to enter the $SeriesNameOrNum exactly how they appear in the embedded worksheets. So I found the relevant worksheet and copied and pasted the series name from there. They now include even the line breaks as per the worksheet i.e 'Jan 2016 Campaign #1' now has a line break after 2016.